# Filtering click element event with matching css selector to an object

Tags: google-tag-manager

I've ran into a problem and can't seem to get the GTM to register the event specifically.

Here is how the HTML looks like for the element that I need to register when someone clicks on it.

```
<div class="targetDiv option option-hoverable">
    <div class="shape">
      <svg width="140" height="140" viewBox="0 0 140 140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
        <title>Shape + Shape + Shape</title>
            <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
              <g transform="translate(0 0)" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" fill="none">
                <circle id="Shape" fill="#CFDF80" cx="40" cy="84.434" r="40"></circle>
                <circle id="Shape" fill="#FDE9E8" cx="80" cy="40" r="40"></circle>
                <circle fill="#E2506E" cx="100" cy="100" r="40"></circle>
              </g>
      </svg>
    </div>

                <h3>Product Title</h3>
                <div class="actions">
                <a class="button button-subtle button-toggle" data-colors="tender" data-toggled="Select" href="">Select</a>
                </div> 
</div>
```

I can't get the Click to register on the outter DIV click, it registers wither the button click or the click on shapes. I need it to register on the DIV with class targetDiv.

I'm getting correct Click triggers from other places, so listening isn't a problem.

Right now the trigger is set like this:

Trigger Type - Click - all elements

Trigger fires on some clicks.

And the conditions are:

Click Element -> matches CSS selector -> targetDiv

Answer (score 0):

This

```
Click Element -> matches CSS selector -> targetDiv
```

wants to match a `<targetDiv>` element, which is not present in your html code.

Try writing a dot before the classname, since that is how you can write a css selector for a class:

```
Click Element -> matches CSS selector -> .targetDiv
```